# Can someone identify this white flowering plant?

Tags: identification, flowers, shrubs

*click for original picture context*

[image]

Can someone help me identify this plant that resembles honeysuckle?

Answer (score 3):

It's not a honeysuckle (Lonicera) - judging by the leaves and the shape of the flowers, plus the 'bobbles' on the stamens, it's most likely a Rhododendron (in particular, those formerly known as Azalea) hybrid, probably a fragrant one, but I don't know which one - there are hundreds, if not thousands, many of which are not named.

The site you got that picture from is, in fact, a fragrance/perfumery site - 'honeysuckle fragrance' does not mean the scent necessarily came from a honeysuckle plant.

UPDATE 18/10/14: This plant is, in fact, [*Rhododendron arborescens*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhododendron_arborescens), commonly known as sweet azalea. It's strongly fragranced, said to be similar to heliotrope, and is deciduous.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely an ericaceous shrub.  looks like [*Rhododendron viscosum*](http://www.wildflower.org/plants/result.php?id_plant=RHVI2), commonly known as swamp azalea.

Comment: Can you add to your answer as to why it looks like that to you? Perhaps a picture or identifying characteristics?